# How to set loading symbol exactly after the grid view ends in android?

Tags: android-layout, gridview, android

I want to add a loading symbol or load more button at the bottom of the gridview when the list ends. when you look into play store app it uses a similar behaviour it has a similar gridview and when u scroll down then there is a loading symbol while loading items.

In listview we can use footers to achieve this but in gridview thats not possible. And i went through some answers already in stackoverflow like setting the visibility of view etc., but nothing is perfect. This sounds like a normal scenario which everyone may encounter but i couldnt find a perfect way to do it!

Comment: This should help you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21157356/1008278

Comment: Thank you... But can u give some idea for modifying it for footer view?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107736/how-to-add-a-footer-to-gridview-layout-in-android